# Importing @type/ziggy-js causes vite to throw an error

Tags: typescript, laravel, vite, inertiajs, ziggy

I have a project using Laravel Inertia, Ziggy, Vue3, Vite, and Typescript. The `route()` function is working just fine, I can visit pages and make requests.

However, Typescript throws an IDE error (in PHPStorm, if it matters) about it as it doesn't know about the global function.

I installed the `@types/ziggy-js` package to fix this, and then Typescript wants me to import the type definition. OK so I do that, but then Vite starts throwing errors because it can't find the file.

Google says add `type` after `import`, but when I do that Typescript says `'route' cannot be used as a value because it was imported using 'import type'.`. I tried every suggested fix for that as well and none work.

The only thing I have gotten to work is re-declaring `route()` as a variable and setting its type to the imported `route`:

```
import type {default as _route} from 'ziggy-js'

let route: typeof _route
```

I feel like there has got to be a better way to go about this than to do this in every file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY got this solved!! Maybe not the cleanest solution, but it works and with minimal repetition.

Turns out that importing a type and assigning it to `route` caused issues with `route()` no longer working outside of a `form.method()` context.

What I did was:

- Copy the `index.d.ts` from `@types/ziggy-js` to my own `resources/js/@types/ziggy-js.d.ts`
- Wrap the contents in a `declare module '@ziggy-js' {}` and change `declare function` to `export function`
- Alias `'@ziggy-js'` to `'./vendor/tightenco/ziggy/src/js/index.js'` in tsconfig/vite.config
- Add `import route from '@ziggy-js'` to the .vue components in which I use `route()`
- Profit